# Excel is not using the cell format immediately

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007, apache-poi

I'm having a problem with the Java Apache POI libary and Excel 2007. The problem is the Cell Format is not being used until I open the workbook, click the cell, and then press enter. The Cell has the correct format, but will not display this format until the steps just listed occur. I made sure that my Excel has Automatic Calculation on, and I even tried doing `wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();` right before closing it. Anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

TLDR: The problem is the Cell Format is not being used until I open the workbook, click the cell, and then press enter.

Edit (I cannot post my code up, but this is the order it is ran in):

```
dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("0.00%"));
selectedCell = getCell(r,c).setCellStyle(style);
selectedCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
selectedCell.setCellFormula(value.substring(1,value.length()));
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Please post your Java code that creates and uses the cell formatting, plus the version of Apache POI you're using.

Comment: I cannot post all of my code, but I will edit my post and add the important parts.

Comment: If instead of setting a formula to get the desired value, you change the type to NUMERIC and set the result directly as a number, does that format properly? (That answer should help you narrow down the cause of the problem)